# How can I access the state that is not in the store in React?

Tags: reactjs, redux, state, react-state

I have a sequence diagram on the left side of my page and I have logs on the right. I use react-json-inspector library. This is provides list of logs. But I have a problem. When I clicked text of sequence diyagram , it goes to the item in the list. But the item in the list does not expand. There is an expand event in the library. I need to get to the state to expand this element. But it only renders initially. I need to reach the state that appears in this image. But this state is not inside my store. How can I access the state used by this library?

[image]

library link : https://github.com/Lapple/react-json-inspector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**State is an internal responsibility of a component. You can't change it from outside** - you can rerender component with changed props. Component **can** update internal state using changed prop.

This library/component does't look like interactively data-driven - it can be only initialized with some presets:

> **props.isExpanded**
>
> Optional predicate that can determine whether the > leaf node should be expanded **on initial render**.

**You can extend this component** to be aware of additional property (f.e. `selectedNode`) - highlight/expand desired item (on start and change of this prop).

Comment: How I can do it last?

Comment: I wrote about a general pattern - how it can/should be done. Details? Fork this project and customize to your needs - dig into code, find out how it works and adapt - you can use `getDerivedStateFromProps` or `componentDidUpdate` - details are up to you.